# Display dropdown items in Option Tag

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to figure out a way when the user selects more then one checkbox, it shows in the option and expands if the user selects more then one. So currently, this is how it is being displayed:

[image]

As you can see above, I am able have the user to select multiple checkboxes but I would like it to do something like this:

[image]

So it would display in the select option box but rather in a row, the results are display in columns with the check boxes.

Any help would be appreciated and the below is what I did:

**HTML:**

```
<td colspan="4">
    <div class="multiselect">
        <div class="selectBox" onclick="showCheckboxes()">
            <select>
                <option value="" disabled selected hidden>Select an option</option>
            </select>
        </div>
        <div id="checkboxes">
            <label for="one"><input type="checkbox" id="one"/>Replacement</label>
            <label for="two"><input type="checkbox" id="two"/>Additional Position </label>
            <label for="three"><input type="checkbox" id="three"/>New Title/Position</label>
        </div>
</div></td>
```

**CSS:**

```
        .multiselect {
            width: 200px;
        }
        .selectBox {
            position: relative;
        }
        .selectBox select {
            width: 100%;
            font-weight: bold;
        }
        .overSelect {
            position: absolute;
            left: 0; right: 0; top: 0; bottom: 0;
            text-align:center;
        }
        #checkboxes {
            display: none;
            border: 1px #dadada solid;

        }
        #checkboxes label {
            display: block;
        }
        #checkboxes label:hover {
            background-color: white;
        }
```

**JAVASCRIPT:**

```
 var expanded = false;
 function showCheckboxes() {
    var checkboxes = document.getElementById("checkboxes");
    if (!expanded) {
        checkboxes.style.display = "block";
        expanded = true;
    } else {
        checkboxes.style.display = "none";
        expanded = false;
    }
 }
```

Comment: I would like to help you, but I've to be honest that I can't follow what you're try to do. First I thought you want to make an select-dropdown where all options you select there shown up as value in the closed select-element. But I don't understand what you try to do with these checkboxes. Could you be a little more specific about what you target is. Somethins like: 1. User clicks dropdown / 2. Dropdown opens and user select / 3. This and that should happen in xy element / 4. But if checkbox selected then abc. (and do you want a raw javascript solution or is jquery also good for you?)

Comment: @Sascha Thank you for your reply and I do apologize for not being clearer: 1. I would like the selected option(s) (if more then one option is selected) to appear where "Select your options" is located. I hope I was able to clear up any confusion

Comment: @Sascha Javacript would be best. I am still new to Javascript and barely starting to understand it. So to rehash want I would like the target to do is: 1. User clicks dropdown / 2. Dropdown opens and user selects an option(s) / 3. Options will appear where "Select your Options" is located. / 4. click arrow for dropdown to close but selected options appear

Answer (score 2):

This code will set the OPTION element's text to match the checked inputs:

```
document.getElementById('checkboxes').addEventListener('change', function(e) {
  var checked = document.querySelectorAll('#checkboxes input:checked'),
      text = [];

  for(var i = 0 ; i < checked.length ; i++) {
    text.push(checked[i].parentNode.textContent.trim());
  }
  document.querySelector('select option').textContent = 
      text.join(', ') || 'Select an option';
});
```

**How it works:**

This adds an event listener on the `checkboxes` DIV, which is triggered whenever one of its inputs gets changed:

```
document.getElementById('checkboxes').addEventListener('change', function(e) {
```

This grabs all the checked INPUT elements:

```
var checked = document.querySelectorAll('#checkboxes input:checked'),
```

These lines create an array with the `textContent` of each checked INPUT element's parent (the LABEL elements):

```
text = [];

for(var i = 0 ; i < checked.length ; i++) {
  text.push(checked[i].parentNode.textContent.trim());
}
```

This sets the text of the OPTION element to be a comma-separated list of the LABEL text.  If none of the INPUTs are checked, then it defaults to 'Select an option':

```
document.querySelector('select option').textContent = 
     text.join(', ') || 'Select an option';
```

**Snippet:**

```js
var expanded = false;

function showCheckboxes() {
  var checkboxes = document.getElementById("checkboxes");
  if (!expanded) {
    checkboxes.style.display = "block";
    expanded = true;
  } else {
    checkboxes.style.display = "none";
    expanded = false;
  }
}

document.getElementById('checkboxes').addEventListener('change', function(e) {
  var checked = document.querySelectorAll('#checkboxes input:checked'),
    text = [];

  for (var i = 0; i < checked.length; i++) {
    text.push(checked[i].parentNode.textContent.trim());
  }
  
  document.querySelector('select option').textContent = 
    text.join(', ') || 'Select an option';
});
```

```css
.multiselect {
  width: 200px;
}
.selectBox {
  position: relative;
}
.selectBox select {
  width: 300px;
  font-weight: bold;
}
.overSelect {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  text-align: center;
}
#checkboxes {
  display: none;
  border: 1px #dadada solid;
}
#checkboxes label {
  display: block;
}
#checkboxes label:hover {
  background-color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="multiselect">
  <div class="selectBox" onclick="showCheckboxes()">
    <select>
      <option value="" disabled selected hidden>Select an option</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <div id="checkboxes">
    <label for="one">
      <input type="checkbox" id="one" />Replacement</label>
    <label for="two">
      <input type="checkbox" id="two" />Additional Position</label>
    <label for="three">
      <input type="checkbox" id="three" />New Title/Position</label>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Ah, that was what he wanted. ^^ But some question Rick, how do you made the snippet toggle-able here on stack overflow?

Comment: When you create a new Snippet, you'll see an option to "Hide snippet by default."

Comment: @Rick: Would it be possible instead side by side, to be stacked? Meaning if I select Replacement and let say Additional Position, Additional Position will appear below Replacement?

Comment: That's possible, but you can't do it with an OPTION element.  Since this question was how to do it in column format, you may want to post a new question as to how to do it in row format.

Comment: Ahh Okay, thank you for you help. It is greatly appreciated.

Comment: I have tried your suggestion but it does not appear.

Comment: Does it work if you place it between <script></script> tags at the bottom of your HTML?  If so, then I'll give you instructions for using document ready.

Comment: I am using the following script tag:<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>. Am I using the wrong one?

Comment: You could simplify your code since you're using jQuery, but we'll work with what you've got.  Place your code like this:  `$( document ).ready(function() {  YOUR CODE GOES HERE });`  See https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/